# Change the format of a word in Emacs-AUCTeX without actually selecting it

Tags: emacs, lisp, auctex

One nice feature of modern word processors is that one can change the format (say, from roman to italic) of a word without actually selecting it; one just needs to place the text cursor within the word and tell the word processor (via a keyboard shortcut) to change its format. (Smart editing, I believe it is sometimes called.)

Is there a way of doing that in Emacs-AUCTeX? (The usual way to change the format---that is, insert a format command---is to select the word [mark its region] and then press the key combination for the command [e.g. `C-c C-f C-i` to insert `\textit{}`].)

Comment: The function would still be selecting the word (but just doing it for you), and then (in the same function) you could call the snippet that makes the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortcut <kbd>C-c C-f</kbd> calls `TeX-font`. Then it emphasizes/italicizes/whatever,
based on the last key chord. So the solution is to advice this function:

```
(defvar TeX-font-current-word t)

(defadvice TeX-font (before TeX-font-word (replace what))
  "If nothing is selected and `TeX-font-current-word' is not nil,
mark current word before calling `TeX-font'."
  (when (and TeX-font-current-word 
             (not replace)
             (not (region-active-p))
             (not (looking-at "\\s-")))
    (unless (looking-back "\\s-") (backward-word))
    (mark-word)))

(ad-activate 'TeX-font)
```

Now, when no region is selected, `TeX-font` will work as if the current word
was selected. You can turn this behavior on/off by setting `TeX-font-current-word` to `t`/`nil`.

Comment: Cool! The only problem is when the point is placed in white space (even at an EOL). It automatically modifies the following word (even the first word of the following line). Can this be fixed?

Comment: What's your desired behavior? It's not obvious what to do in that situation.

Comment: If in whitespace, just insert the macro.

Comment: @AndreasRöhler Where should that go exactly?

Comment: @NVaughan Erm, correcting it: instead of (mark-word) in original this should do it:     (push-mark (car (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'word)))
    (goto-char (cdr (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'word)))

Comment: What's the problem with the current approach?

Comment: @AndreasRöhler It disables the functionality of abo-abo's solution.

Comment: (mark-word) will mark the following word also. Using "bounds-..." was to replace just this. No further idea for now, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In case there is no solution right from the spot, Emacs offers two ways basically once the succession of commands/keys is known:

either store them into a keyboard-macro, which be might called with just one key - or put all the commands into a function, make it a command, assign a key.